# Issues switching from natbib to biblatex; %-symbol in howpublished field and style from .bst file

Tags: biblatex

I would need to have two bibliographies in my work and it seems this is rather tricky to do with natbib. Thus I thought I would move over to biblatex as printing two different bibliographies with it is very simple. But now I'm presented with the following three problems:

1. I have urls in some of my "howpublished" fields. For example:

   ```
   \@misc{aaa,
   author = "Author 1",
   title = {A website},
   howpublished = "Available from: \url{www.website.com/%20/%20abc}",
   }
   ```

In natbib this works fine but in biblatex the "%" symbol is interpreted as a commented an I receive errors. I know that the "url" field would work but this would not provide me with the desired bibliography format and flexibility I get with using the "howpublished" field. Is there a way I can have a % symbol in the bibliography entry?

2. If I have understood correctly I can not use the trusted .bst file I have modified to my liking? If so I would need to find a style where the in text citations are in the format of "Author (2015)" and "(Author, 2015)". The bibliography should be in the format of "Grösche, P. & C. Schröder (2014). On the redistributive effects of Germany’s feed-in tariff. *Empirical Economics 46*(4), 1339–1383."
3. Some long urls or titles go beyond the margins in the bibliography. In natbib this didn't happen and all my references fit within the margins. Is there an automated solution for this or do I need to manually edit the problematic entries?

If these issues could be solved I'd be happy to switch over to biblatex but I haven't been able to solve these on my own or by the resources I've found googling around.

Comment: If I understand your objective correctly, you need to create a document that has two separate bibliographies. Have you looked into using the [bibunits](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/bibunits) package? The package's user guide states that it is compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: Well I wouldn't need two bib files if I was able to use natbib as I could use the commands:

\printbibliography[type=article]
\printbibliography[type=misc

This would yield my desired result and would be extremely easy. I'll need to look into bibunits and see if it can do what I want. I don't need bibliographies for chapters or anything like that, just need to separate online and non-online sources.

Comment: bibunits seems to designed for creating bibliographies from parts of the document. I want to have 2 bibliographies at the end of my document that are simply separated by style. Is bibunits suited for this?

Comment: For ways to create mutiple bibliographies, do check out the packages mentioned in the UK TeX FAQ entry [Multiple bibliographies](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=multbib).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Did I understand correctly that using the multibbl or multibib topics would mean I would need to define each cite on what bibliography they belong to? I have probably 400 different \citep or \citet commands on my work so defining everyone of these would be a massive chore. Thus it seems the biblatex way of doing things would be clearly superior... If I could only solve the 3 issues mentioned in my initial post. If I misunderstood the way the multibib and multibbl packages I apologise, I'm not well versed in latex or code in general.

Comment: I must confess I don't fully understand your setup and objectives. May I suggest you post a new query, in which you explain the objectives and constraints in more detail?

Comment: Well I'll try to summarise it: I want 2 bibliographies, one for articles and one for online sources. All my articles are in my .bib file as "article" and online sources are as "misc". Thus if I could print one bibliography with just the "article" entries and other with "misc" entries. I can do this easily with biblatex but there are the 3 issues I've listed in my first post.

Comment: Do you have the ability to sort the bib file into two parts -- say, entries of type `@article` and all others? If so, you could create two separate bib files and use the `bibtopic` package to create the separate bibliographies in a more or less automatic fashion.

Comment: Yes, it would take a bit of work but not more than 15-30min so very doable. After a quick look at the bibtopic manual it seems like exactly what I need! As long as it is fully compatible with the natbib commands (e.g \citet and \citep and \citealias) this should do the trick. I'll look into it once I get back to my latex document.

Comment: The `bibtopic` manual claims that it's compatible with `natbib`.

Comment: Well natbib seems simple enough but I can't even get the minimal example laid out in the manual to work! I can't seem to get it to recognise my .bib file and thus can't cite anything. If I add the command \usepackage{bibtopic} to my existing document all my citations created by natbib disappear.

Comment: The error I receive is: 
"Package bibtopic Warning: Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):
(bibtopic) texstudio_LT68321
(bibtopic) texstudio_LT68322
(bibtopic) and after that rerun LaTeX."

I have no idea what this means and what reruning bibtex means.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm absolutely no good at divination. Without an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5001), I simply can't venture a meaningful guess as to how you should proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The `biblatex` way to handle web sites and other electronic references is to  use

```
@online{aaa,
  author = {Author 1},
  title = {A website},
  url = {www.website.com/%20/%20abc},
}
```

If one uses `biber` as backend, then it is possible to remap dynamically the entry types and fields.

Comment: Yes I know this is the way to handle it. My question was is there anyway to have a % symbol in any of the other fields without messing up the syntax. Like in my example I would like to have it on the "howpublished" field.